# pygame looping round array to work out where to draw

Tags: python

I am quite new to pygame and am trying to loop round my array to check that when drawing out the sprite's inventory, it will draw the items from the top down. For example,

```
[empty]
[empty]
[empty]
```

In this case, if the player picked up an item it would draw it in the first slot.

```
[wood]
[empty]
[empty]
```

Now, if the player picked up another item, it would draw it in the second slot.

```
inventory = {"logs": 10, "stones": 0, "sword": "none", "pickaxe": "none"}

slots = [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]

if inventory["logs"] > 0: 
    y = 90 #coordinate to draw the logs
    for i in slots:
        if i == "logs":
            break
        elif i == True:
            y += 90
        else:
            slots[i] = "logs"
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load("logs.png"), (invX, y)) '''draws the image 
    into the inventory area'''

if inventory["stones"] > 0:
        y = 90
        for i in slots:
            if i == "stones":
                break
            elif i == True:
                y += 90
            else:
                slots[i] = "stones"
        screen.blit(pygame.image.load("stones.png"), (invX, y))
```

This is not all the code but hopefully all that is needed. Firstly I am given the error list indices must be integers or slices, not str and secondly, it will draw the stones and logs image on top of each other.

Comment: what is the problem in your code?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the problem but have no updated it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `for i in slots:` each i is an actual element of your list and not just a number index. You should change the brackets to this:

```
else:
    slots[slots.index(i)] = "logs"
```